# C++ How do i display the input like a receipt after the user has typed them

Tags: c++

Hi im creating a cinema ticket operator as a self short project but i am a bit stuck on how to make the results of what the user inputs show up at the end summed up like on a receipt. Thanks in advance.

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int selectStaff();
int selectDate();
int selectMovie();
int printReceipt(int a);
string name, date;

int main()
{
int movie;

selectStaff();
date = selectDate();
movie = selectMovie();
printReceipt(movie);

return 0;
}
int printReceipt(int a) 
{
if (a == 1) {
cout << "Deadpool" << endl;
}
else {
cout << "Goosebumps" << endl;
}

return 0;
}

int selectStaff() {
cout << "Welcome to FILM Screen Cinema" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "ENTER STAFF/OPERATOR'S NAME: " << endl;
cin >> name;

return 0;
}

int selectDate() {
cout << endl;
cout << "ENTER DATE:";
cin >> date;

return 0;
}

int selectMovie() {
int movie;

cout << endl;
cout << "CHOOSE A MOVIE THAT IS SCREENING TODAY:" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Press 1 for first option & 2 for second option" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "[1] Deadpool" << endl << "[2] Goosebumps" << endl;
cin >> movie;

return 0;
}
```

I want all the required input to be displayed at the bottom so when it prints, the user can view the summary. I also need a closing message that says "thank you"

Comment: We are not your homework monkeys.

Comment: i said self short project how does that imply homework?

Comment: What have you tried? If you want to learn the language, you should be able to easily find information on how to do this. You also posted another question on this same code earlier. If you are really just trying to learn, I suggest you study some more before attempting a self-project.

Comment: Probably because he thinks it stands for Command Line Interface.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have all of the variables lined up to do this neatly and simply. Just edit your print receipt function to look something like:

```
Int printreceipt(int a) { 
string title; 
if (a==1) { 
title = "Deadpool"; 
} else { 
title == "Goosebumps"; 
} 
cout << "Cashier: "; cout << name << endl << endl; //say the operator's name and add a line
cout << "Date: " << date << endl; //say the date
 cout << "Movie: " << title; //say the title of the movie
 cout << endl << endl; //add a line
 cout << "Thank you for choosing this cinema! Enjoy!"; //Thank you message :D
}
```

To give you results similar to:

```
Cashier: Guy

Date: May 5, 2017
Movie: Deadpool
Thank you for choosing this cinema! Enjoy!
```